# Google CSE(Custom Search Engine) how set query to GA(Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, google-custom-search

I use google cse as my site search.

Google support page: [support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264)

Take this example: `www.google.com?hl=en&q=xxx`. So the *Query Parameter* is `q`. And my site is with google cse, the query action will direct to url like this: `https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=xxx&q=xxx...#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%23C&gsc.page=1`

My Google Analytics report cannot get query words from this case.
Google Analytics can get the word only on directly enter the url like this `http://site?q=xxx`.

But I use google cse instead of myself site's search. 
How can I set the correct settings ?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a custom search element or the standard code?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem and I think you must be using:

```
<gcse:searchbox-only> and <gcse:searchresults-only>
```

If you are then you have to customise the javascript code segment with the resultsURL element.

> resultsUrl    URL The URL of the results page. (Default is the Google-hosted page.)

From [Custom Search Element Control API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element).

```
<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="http://www.yourWeb.com"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```